# How to get the value from a javascript array in html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application where i have one set of data in a table and  i will click on the row of that table and a pop up will generate and the data will be added in a new table below that table.So the situation is pretty simple.Now my problem is that i have to do two operations on that  below table  one is delete and another is update .Now the problem is that for editing and deleting i have to pass the id of  each row to another function ,where i will do the respective operations.so the problem is that when i am clicking on the row of the upper table that is adding the data to the below table ,for example lets say there is only one row in the upper table i have added it to the below table now i can do update and delete operation in the below table.But when i am adding one more row from the upper table  while adding the new row to the below table the id of the newly inserted row is replacing the older one in the new table.I am showing my code what  i have done

```
for(var z=0; z<data.searchResultArray.length;z++){  


     searchResultArray = data.searchResultArray[z].split("$$##$$##");   


     createTable = createTable + "<tr><td>"+searchResultArray[0]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[1]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[2]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[3]+"</td><td>"+"<a href =#  onclick=deleteCandidate(searchResultArray[5],searchResultArray[6]);  target=\"_self\">"+"Delete"+"</a></td><td>"+"<a href =#  onclick=updatePresentCandidatePopUp(searchResultArray[5],searchResultArray[6]);  target=\"_self\">"+"Edit"+"</a></td></tr>";  

        $(".homeSearchResultOutside1").html(createTable+"</tbody></table>");
        alert(createTable)
        $('#mainTable1').dataTable({

            "scrollY":        300,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "jQueryUI":       true,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "iDisplayLength": 20, 
            "aLengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]]
        });

    }
```

so the searchResultArray[5] and searchResultArray[6] is updating each time while inserting a new row ,how to manage that??[image]

Comment: `$().html()` replaces the content. try `$().append()` to append the data to existing content.

Comment: @JSantosh did not get you i need entire table to be formed but each row will get their id s only not the updated one

Comment: provide a fiddle or demo page. @lucifer

Comment: At a glance, it makes little or no sense to do: `$('#mainTable1').dataTable({...` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work, I modified your code a bit based ONLY on assumptions on my part but perhaps it will work as a starting point for you.  Note it IS a bit on the verbose side but I opted for that to make the intent clear.

```
var rStart = "<tr><td>";
var rEnd = "</td></tr>";
var tdEnd = "</td><td>";
var splitString = "$$##$$##";

var cTableStart = "<table><tbody>";
var cTableEnd = "</tbody></table>";
var createTable = cTableStart;
var z = 0;
for (z = 0; z < data.searchResultArray.length; z++) {
    var searchArray = data.searchResultArray[z].split(splitString); // must assume 7 (0-6) split elements in string
    var rowItems = "\"" + searchArray[5] + "\",\"" + searchArray[6] + "\"";
    var rowDelete = "<a href =# onclick='deleteCandidate(" + rowItems + ")' target='_self'>Delete</a>";
    var rowUpdate = "<a href =# onclick='updatePresentCandidatePopUp(" + rowItems + ")' target='_self'>Edit</a>";
    var newRow = rStart + searchArray[0] + tdEnd + searchArray[1] + tdEnd + searchArray[2] + tdEnd + searchArray[3] + tdEnd + rowDelete + tdEnd + rowUpdate + rEnd;
    createTable = createTable + newRow;
}
createTable = createTable + cTableEnd;
$(".homeSearchResultOutside1 ").html(createTable);
//alert(createTable);

// We have no insight into the table #mainTable1 here - perhaps need to modify cTableStart above
//NOTE Datatables 1.9 & prior ONLY syntax: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref
$('#mainTable1').dataTable({
    "scrollY": 300,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "jQueryUI": true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "aLengthMenu": [
        [20, 50, 100, -1],
        [20, 50, 100, "All"]
    ]
});
```